# Input data and print print_area

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a complete beginner to Excel VBA, but I'm trying to create a user form (for use in multiple work books) to print off charts from the spreadsheets within them, but first I need to set the date ranges in to two cells for it to collate the information for the charts.

Is there any way of doing this using VBA?

This is What I have managed to get so far, but it just automatically runs instead of waiting for the print button to be pressed:

```
Sub PrintChart_Click()

Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
StartDate = txtdatestart.Value
EndDate = txtdateend.Value

Cells(2, 3) = StartDate
Cells(3, 3) = EndDate
```

Sheets("Dashboard").Range("Charts").PrintOut

```
End Sub
```

Comment: @Passmore: you might want to share sample data

Comment: @JurPertin I'm not entirely sure what sort of sample data I am able to share due to data protection. 

Basically, on Sheet1 we have a variety of information (dates, reference numbers, names, codes etc.) all inputted via a VBA userform. This information is then shown via graph form  on 3 separate graphs in one sheet, but only once you have entered a start date and end date in to C2 (start) and C3 (end). I've been asked to see if it is possible to print off the 3 graphs (or a print area including the graphs) using a userform with input boxes for the dates?

Comment: @Passmore: I understand your situation. However, no one will be able to help you without looking at the code you have or at least some section of it.

Comment: @JurPertin added above

Comment: @JurPertin I've edited the post to show what i've managed to cobble together so far.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is what i had managed to find

```
Sub PrintChart_Click()

Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
StartDate = txtdatestart.Value
EndDate = txtdateend.Value

Sheets("Dashboard").Cells(2, 3) = StartDate
Sheets("DashBoard").Cells(3, 3) = EndDate

Sheets("Dashboard").Range("Charts").PrintOut

Sheets("Dashboard").Cells(2, 3) = ""
Sheets("Dashboard").Cells(3, 3) = ""

End Sub
```

This seems to work quite well.